# RegEx not working in MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab

I have not done any RegEx work in MATLAB, I do not think this is an environment issue but I am not sure. Here is my task:

1. Download NASDQ stock data from   ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/symboldirectory/nasdaqtraded.txt
2. Extract all stock symbols using a RegEx
3. Here is the RegEx that I created: ^[A-Z]\|([A-Z]+)\|.+\|[A-Z]\|[A-Z]\|[A-Z]\|\d\d\d\|[A-Z]\|[A-Z]\|.*\|[A-Z]+$

This expression works on some, but not all lines in this file. For example, it works perfectly for this line: 
 - Y|AAPL|Apple Inc. - Common Stock|Q|Q|N|100|N|N||AAPL

However it does not match anything from this line:
 - Y|A|Agilent Technologies, Inc. Common Stock|N| |N|100|N||A|A
 - Y|AAMC|Altisource Asset Management Corp Com|A| |N|100|N||AAMC|AAMC

Help please...thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can make a reasonable regex for stock symbols, because I dont think that the symbols have specific rules on naming. In other words, a symbol can be almost anything

Comment: I just took a look at the text file.  There are so many variations of the formatting for the lines that I don't think you can write one `regex` that will succinctly capture what you're looking for.

Comment: You should try first splitting the fields which are separate by | and then work with the individual fields. Assuming fields themselves do not have |, you should be able to do this easily using strfind or simple ==

Comment: Thanks, it seems that this is not the approach that should be taken, I found this and can properly parse a CSV file 
http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file seems to be a set of columns delimited with `|`, with first line being column names.

Here is a solution to create directly structure array whose field names are obtained from column names:

```
function [structArray] = ReadNasdaqTraded(filename)
%[
    % For debug
    if (nargin < 1), filename = 'nasdaqtraded.txt'; end 

    % Read full file content
    text = fileread(filename);

    % Split on newline
    text = strsplit(strtrim(text), '\n');    
    header = text{1}; % Keep header
    content = text(2:(end-1)); % Keep content
    footer = text{end}; %#ok - We don't care about last line  (file creation date)

    % Build suitable field names
    fieldNames = strsplit(header, '|');
    fieldNames = strtrim(fieldNames); % Remove any
    fieldNames = strrep(fieldNames, ' ', ''); % spaces (TODO: OR special characters)

    % Reformat content into cell matrix
    count = length(content);
    columnCount = length(fieldNames);
    cellArray = cell(count, columnCount);
    for ri = 1:count,
        cellArray(ri, :) = strsplit(content{ri}, '|', 'CollapseDelimiters', false); % Carefull not to collapse empty delimiters
    end

    % Create structure array from cell content
    structArray = cell2struct(cellArray, fieldNames, 2);    
%]
```

It returns some result like this:

```
>> ReadNasdaqTraded('nasdaqtraded.txt')

ans = 

8188x1 struct array with fields:

    NasdaqTraded
    Symbol
    SecurityName
    ListingExchange
    MarketCategory
    ETF
    RoundLotSize
    TestIssue
    FinancialStatus
    CQSSymbol
    NASDAQSymbol
```

Easy to use then for whatever extra processing you need ...

Comment: You are a savior @CitizenInsane